# youtubeinmp3's api direct link returns html page instead of mp3 file

Tags: python, html, json, api, mp3

I tried to write my own Python code to download multiple youtube videos as mp3 files using youtubeinmp3 API. It worked just fine for most of the files but some were 46Kb HTML pages instead of mp3. Is there any way I can make my code solve this problem on its own?

Here goes the script :

```
import urllib, json, re

#List of Youtube Video IDs to download
ListofURL = open("list.txt","r")
Ids = [url.strip().replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','') for url in ListofURL.readlines()]

#Base url
url = "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/format=JSON&video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="

for id in Ids:

    #Getting the API's download link as json response
    response = urllib.urlopen(url+id)
    data = json.loads("{" + re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', response.read())[0] + "}")

    #Creating a file to download the song to
    target = open(data["title"]+".mp3", 'wb')

    #Downloading the mp3
    mresponse = urllib.urlopen(data["link"])
    mdata = mresponse.read()

    #saving Data to the created file
    target.write(mdata)

    #closing the created file
    target.close()
```

The script reads youtube addresses from a file in this format :

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzpa6ACrZaQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B_3g_9gtFQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ex0Hli7kMRs
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show  how these _ HTML pages_ break your code?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way... i tried doing this myself. some of the videos are blocked, some others are not in their db, so they won't download and the download.htm takes their place, which is the youtubeinmp3 page that simply redirects into itself..  i think it is specially done by the webmaster to try and spread their ads and malware looking ads.. not good, but what can one do...

and there's no way to check. i actually tried getting headers for the final download link, and did it with "wget --spider URL", so as to check if the ffinal redirect resolves to an mp3 or a page. and even if it resolves to mp3, when i try and download it - it still sometimes reverts to that download.htm.

there are other youtube to mp3 apis. i have implemented "method2" with a different api, which actually has progress indicator and other stuff.. although i had to hack around to extract the download link there, cause it wants to push its own ads too...

check out the site http://youtubemp3.today/ and see how it works and switches from 1 (youtubeinmp3) to the other one..